# Work done along a closed curve is zero but field is not conservative. How can that be?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For example lets say we have this vector field:

$$F=<xz,yz,xy>$$

Compute

$$\int\int_S Fdr$$

where $s$ is part of the sphere $$x^2+y^2+z^2=4$$ that lies inside the cylinder $$x^2+y^2=1$$

The integral comes out to be zero but F is not conservative. How can that be?

Comment: I know line integral is the work done but what is the relation between surface integral and work?

Comment: $$\int\int_S curlF n ds = \int\int_CFdr$$ It is Stokes theorem. But I saw myself it didn't make sense the way I wrote it so I changed it! That means that the curl of F should be zero but it isn't.

Comment: I think you confused line integral with surface integral. In your example, are you talking about the line integral along the curve of the intersection? If that's the case, the work is 0. Because the field moves in xy-plane, but the curve is above and parallel to xy-plane.

Comment: Why do you think the fact that the integral along a certain closed curve/surface vanishes can imply the field is conservative?

Comment: If the curl of F is zero that means that the field is conservative. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @KittyL since the work is zero that means the the curlF is zero according the Stokes theorem. But when I calculate the curlF it is not zero. I am just wondering what I have misunderstood.

Comment: If the curl of F is zero, F is defined in the entire domain, and F has continuous partial derivatives, then F is conservative. In your example though, the curl of F is not zero, and F is not conservative. So what is wrong?

Comment: The work is zero does not mean the curl F is zero. It means, by Stokes theorem, $\iint \nabla \times F\cdot dS$ is zero. Or it means the direction of curl F is perpendicular to the normal of the surface.

Comment: Sorry I got myself confused! Thank you @KittyL :)

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it.